# Invertibility of bisymmetric matrices

Tags: matrices

I have a bisymmetric matrix, i.e. symmetric with respect to both diagonals, and I want to show it's nonsingular.

Wikipedia suggests that all eigenvalues of a real bisymmetric matrix have the same absolute value, so finding one nonzero eigenvalue would suffice.

Is there a more simple criteria for determining the invertibility of bisymmetric matrices?

Comment: Some bisymmetrical matrices are singular, so you will need something more for invertibility.  Gerhard "Care To Tell Us What?" Paseman, 2018.06.21.

Comment: Let us look in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisymmetric_matrix again: The inverse of bisymmetric matrices can be represented by recurrence formulas.[2] . We read in [2]: " First, we obtain an explicit inverse formula of bisymmetric matrices. Second, a recurrence algorithm for the inverse is given. Finally, an example is provided to verify the feasibility of the algorithms".

Comment: I don't know where you found that factoid on the eigenvalues, but $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is bisymmetric (if I understand the definition correctly) and its eigenvalues do not all have the same absolute value. In particular, it has a nonzero eigenvalue and it's singular.

Comment: @matt: Let us look in Wikipedia again: the eigenvalues are as you say **"after pre or post multiplication by the exchange matrix"**.

Comment: Yeah that's a bit weird. I think that pre or post multiplication by the exchange matrix results in an also bisymmetric matrix - the 1,1;1,1 example here certainly does

Comment: Yeah I'll check the reference [2] on wikipedia out, the algorithm might shed some light.

Comment: A bit more info is that there are no duplicate rows, it has integer matrices, and the rows and columns alternate in signature. E.g.

1 -2 3;
-2 4 -2;
3 -2 1

Comment: In the paper quoted in the Wikipedia article, there is a condition ensuring that a bisymmetric matrix is invertible. Of course, this is not always satisfied: as remarked above, a matrix with all entries equal is clearly bisymmetric, but singular.

Answer (score 2):

Bisymmetric matrices have a constrained structure, but not so constrained that one can guarantee nonsingularity by looking at a single eigenvalue (unless you have a one-by-one matrix).

Nevertheless, there is enough structure present so that one can meaningfully reduce the amount of work required for eigensystem analysis versus an unstructured matrix.  To see that, here is what one Fields medalist said about [bisymmetric linear systems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39618/bisymmetric-matrix-solving-set-of-linear-equations/39677#39677) at Math Overflow a few years ago.  As Thurston noted, one can effectively split the size of the original eigenspace into two half-sized eigenspaces.  So, one can look for the presence of singularity in two half-sized (off-by-one if odd-dimensioned) symmetric matrices rather than the full sized matrix.

To make this observation concrete, let’s do some light analysis and work out an example.  The matrix $R$ that Thurston refers to is often called the exchange matrix, and can be block diagonalized by the matrix
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left( \begin{array}{cc}
I & \tilde{R} \\
-\tilde{R} & I  \end{array} \right).
\end{equation}

where $\tilde{R}$ is an exchange matrix with half the size of $R$ (insert a $\sqrt 2$ in the center if the dimension is odd).  That is,

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X^T R X} = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
-I & 0 \\
0 & I  \end{array} \right).
\end{equation}

If $X$ is the same size as your bisymmetric matrix (call it $A$), then because $R$ and $A$ commute, it’s easy to see that $X^T A X$ also has a block diagonal structure 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{ X^T A X } = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
\tilde A_{11} & 0 \\
0 & \tilde A_{22}  \end{array} \right).
\end{equation}

where $\tilde A_{11}$ and $\tilde A_{22}$ are block matrices with size matching the corresponding block decomposition of $R$.  One then has two half-sized eigensystems that can be analyzed for singularity (or for the full set of eigenvalues, if desired).

Example: let's look at the bisymmetric matrix
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A} = \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
3 & -2 & -1 & 1  & 1\\
-2  & 1 & -3 & 1 & 0 \\
-1  & -3 & 5 & -3 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -3 & 1 & -2 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & -2 & 3 \end{array} \right).
\end{equation}

Then 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt 2  & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right).
\end{equation}

produces the block diagonal matrix
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X^T A X} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
2 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5 & -\sqrt{18} & -\sqrt2 \\
0 & 0 & -\sqrt{18} & 2 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & -\sqrt 2 & -2 & 4 \end{array} \right).
\end{equation}

The eigenvalues of $A$ can now be obtained from the diagonal blocks of $X^T A X$, and are readily computed to be $-2$, $1-\sqrt 5$, $1 + \sqrt 5$, $5$, and $8$.  Or, since you're interested in checking for singularity, simply take determinants of the two diagonal blocks in this small example.

To clarify the Wikipedia reference regarding the eigenvalues of $A$ following pre or post multiplication by the exchange matrix $R$ (alluded to in your question statement), it is stating that $RA$ and $AR$ will have the same eigenvalues as $A$ *up to sign*.  In the example above, you’ll find that the matrix $RA$ has eigenvalues $-1-\sqrt 5$, $-2$, $-1+\sqrt 5$, $5$, and $8$.  This is the same as the spectrum of $A$ aside from two sign flips.

The fact that $RA$ and $AR$ have the same eigenvalues as a bisymmetric matrix $A$ up to sign is a trivial observation.  The more interesting direction is that if $RA$ and $AR$ have the same eigenvalues up to sign as a given real symmetric matrix $A$, then $A$ and $R$ must commute (i.e., this is a necessary and sufficient condition for a real symmetric matrix $A$ to be bisymmetric).